# Which diphthong takes place in 'desirous'?

Tags: phonetics, diphthongs

The phonetic transcription for *desirous* (in its BrE pronunciation) can be written as [dɪˈz**ʌɪə**rəs]. I wonder which diphthong—ʌɪ or ɪə—takes place in this word? Maybe here we can see a kind of haplology?

Comment: I'd say it's the influence of 'r'. Transitioning from ʌɪ  to the 'r', with some pronunciations of 'r', involves movement of the jaw forward during which movement breath is still coming out resuting in ə.  With some pronunciations of the 'r' there is in the preceding vowel a dipthong only.

Comment: It may also be pronounced without the schwa, as in di-ˈzī(-ə)r-əs as Merriam-Webster shows it, in that case it's just a long 'i' as in "eye".  In the same way that "iris" doesn't usually show a schwa sound.

Comment: @Zebrafish interesting. But is i in _eye_ really long as you said?

Comment: Long 'i' loosely means the sound in 'bribe', 'bride', 'hide', 'wide', as opposed to the 'i' sound in 'bib', 'bid' or 'bit'. The dictionaries I've checked use the same transcription for these long 'i' words as in 'eye', that is, /aɪ/ or /ī/ or /ʌɪ/, depending on which dictionary. The only difference between with or without schwa seems to me to just be a matter of gliding straight into 'r', in a kind of more direct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/ʌɪə/ and /ʌuə/ are triphthongs. They are sometimes phonetically realized as diphthongs, but if all three vowel sounds are pronounced, they are triphthongs.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please give a reference to a work where these triphthongs are described?

Comment: Let me look for my old book of phonetics...

Comment: What English words have /ʌuə/ in them?

Comment: @PeterShor Well, *hour, our, power, sour, dower, shower,* and so many others.

Comment: "lower" is pronounced /ləuə/

Comment: I'm interested in knowing how something like /ə/ can be distinguished from /ər/, seeing as when one pronounces the /r/ it very much sounds like the schwa /ə/ anyway. Edit: What I mean is that is that /r/ sounds like /ər/ to me.

Comment: While these are often described as triphthongs, it’s worth noting that they aren’t to a lot of people. A triphthong is by definition _monosyllabic_, and many (perhaps most) speakers realise these sequences as two syllables (while some others reduce them to a monophthong, as in many BrE and AuE dialects where it’s realised as something like [dɪˡzäː]). A distinction is claimed to exist between monosyllabic /ʌɪə ʌʊə/ (_hire_, _dour_) and disyllabic /ʌɪ.ə ʌʊ.ə/ (_higher_, _dower_), but I have to admit I have rarely heard anyone actually distinguish the number of syllables in these pairs.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Certainly lots of people pronounce *desire* with three syllables, but does anybody pronounce *desirous* with four syllables?

Comment: @PeterShor I would say I vacillate between three and four syllables. I have no distinction between the monosyllabic and disyllabic variants of /ʌɪə/: it’s consistently disyllabic to me, regardless of context. If I pronounce _desirous_ with three syllables, I have no schwa there, just [dɪˡzʌɪ.rəs], so it’s arguably a different phonemic structure (/dɪˡzʌɪ.ər.əs/ vs /dɪˡzʌɪ.rəs/).

Comment: It's only a triphthong when it's all in the same syllable -- like in the word *yay*. Consider the word *hiatus*: there is no triphthong before the T there because the vowels are spread across two syllables.

Answer (score 0):

In my pretty standard version of BrE it is not a tripthong and I've never heard it that way.

I say

[dɪˈzʌɪə] - tripthong, emphasis on **ʌɪ**, silent **r**

but

[dɪˈzʌɪrəs] - dipthong